Is there a way to apply R formula to whole excel sheet
I have the following code to apply in R:
qnorm(0.975)*sqrt(p*(1-p)/n)

Typically, I would enter the individual p and n values to get the output. However, I have a lot of data in Excel format, and to save time, I would like to apply the above code to an attached Excel file in R with data in following format. A sample from the excel file has data in following format:

Thank you very much!

Why not just using Excel formula to deal with it? qnorm(0.975) in R is equivalent to NORM.S.INV(0.975) in Excel. No need to import the excel file into R.

@DarrenTsai Historically, Excel hasn't been trustworthy with distribution functions.

Yes, you need to import your excel file, for example, with the readxl package. You can install it like this;
install.packages("readxl")

Upload the package and read your file:
library(readxl)
df <- read_excel("your file name here")

You can apply your formula in a dplyr pipe:
library(dplyr)
df <- df |>
mutate(result=qnorm(0.975)*sqrt(P*(1-P)/N))

Edit: you can save your dataframe to a CSV- or to an excel-file with writexl or xlxs package.

Why not df$result = with(df, qnorm(.975) * sqrt(P * (1-P) / N)))?

@Friede yes, or even simpler yet: df$result=qnorm(.975)*sqrt(df$P*(1-df$P)/df$N)
